# Ubuntu 14.04 with dell issue

Tags: shutdown, headset, dell-vostro

I am using dell with ubuntu 14.04 LTS (64 bit). 
When I connect headset, the system shutdown automatically. 
Also, I am not able to shutdown the system via the GUI.  However, I can do it by running this command:

```
sudo shutdown now -P
```